# How to open a folder in Ubuntu default file manager via terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, directory, filemanager

I am using Ubuntu.

From my terminal, how can I open my OS default file manager on a certain folder (e.g. on a folder that I view at current directory)?

say I change my current directory to:

`cd /root/dir/`

then I list all the files there:

`ls folder1  folder2  folder3`

Now I want to open folder1.
If I type `./` I get:

`./folder1 bash: ./folder1: Is a directory`

What is the command to make the file manager to open on `folder1`?

Comment: just type  `cd folder1`

Comment: If you want to change directory you should use cd folder1. you used ./folder1 it wont work './' is used to execute an executable file but folder is a directory.

Comment: @user280447 : Mention exact method that you want to open (CLI or GUI) and Linux os: Ubuntu or other?

Comment: What do you mean by "open" it? List the contents? Open it in graphical file manager?

Comment: `xdg-open ./folder1`

Comment: **xdg-open "/your/path"** - 
This is what I was looking for that got me to this page (I'm using a raspberry pi with debian linux)

Answer (score 54):

If you want to open the folder via the nautilus file manager, you can move to the wanted directory like you've mentioned `cd /root/dir/` , check the folders under that path using `ls` and then if you want to open folder1 type:

```
nautilus folder1
```

Comment: I'm on debian and it's `nemo` instead of `nautilus` for me

Comment: nautilus .  to open current folder

Answer (score 17):

`./` is used to execute file (Not to open directory).

(In)**CLI Method**: You can open folder in terminal by `cd folder1` or `dir folder1` or `ls folder1`.

(To)**GUI Method:** If you want to open with file-manager (ex:nautilus) then type`nautilus folder1` (for Ubuntu nautilus is default file-manager)

Answer (score 7):

I have found that simply typing `gnome-open "any-oject"` opens any folder or file in the default program on Ubuntu. 
If this happens to be a folder, it uses your default folder-explorer :)

Comment: `gnome-open /path` works for Redhat (RHEL) as well.

Comment: `kd-open /path` is the equivalent for Kubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

**zsh** shell can do that with the `AUTO_CD` option.

```
bob@tp ~ % setopt AUTO_CD
bob@tp ~ %
bob@tp ~ % ./Documents
bob@tp ~/Documents % 
bob@tp ~/Documents % pwd
/home/bob/Documents
```

Just put `setopt AUTO_CD` in your `.zshrc` file (start **zsh**  one time first to create the **zsh** environment files).
You can invoke directly **zsh** at the terminal prompt to start a **zsh** session or you can change your default shell to be **zsh** with the **chsh** command.

Btw this is not a strange feature, crossable directories do have the "execute" attribute so it makes sense to able to execute a directory like any standard commands.

Answer (score 3):

```
xdg-open /path/to/folder
```

will open the folder `/path/to/folder` in the default file manager.

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the directory using ls, it will give you a list of that contents without moving from your directory

```
ls -al /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22 : To open the current directory use command below (or just nau and TAB then .)

> ```
> nautilus .
> ```