# Problem in renaming the partition and opening a file through terminal

Tags: command-line

I installed Lubunntu 15.10 on my pc  and my ntfs partition which I didn't touched at all named in a very weird way I want to rename it so used the **Disks** to rename after reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions) but it shows this error

> Cannot change label on mounted device of type filesystem:ntfs.
>    (udisks-error-quark, 11)

and I also want to know how to open a file(like I want to execute a python file) through terminal I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464324/how-to-open-a-folder-in-linux-via-terminal) and tried myself but can't figure out. please help as I am new to Lubuntu any suggestions and links to learn bash terminal commands will be helpful. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I got same exception (*Cannot change label on mounted device of type filesystem:ntfs. (udisks-error-quark, 11)*)

I fixed this by following these setup.

1. search Disks and Go to Disks
2. select the partition which you want to rename
3. unmount partition by clicking pause icon
4. by clicking setting icon select Edit Filesystem option
5. change File System Lable popup will show
6. fill name which you want to change
7. finally don't forget to mount the partition

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify partitions that are in use (indicated by a key icon in gparted). If the partition you wish to modify is your system partition, ypu will have to boot with a live USB to change it. Otherwise you can unmount / edit /remount.

*Before performing any actions with `gparted` **back up your system**!*

To change the label on a non-system partition:

1. Start `gparted`
2. Right-click on the partition you want to re-label
3. Select **Unmount**
4. Right-click on the partition you want to re-label
5. Select **Label**
6. Enter the label of your choice
7. Exit `gparted`
8. Reboot or type `sudo mount -a` in a terminal to remount the partition

To change the label on a system partition:

1. Boot the system using a Live USB
2. Follow the procedure above omitting steps 2 and 3, because the partition should not be mounted.

Comment: how to do it with live cd( i can use only that) do i have to reinstall the os?  and whats that other option

Comment: how to unmount edit and remount again

Comment: @Abomm I have expanded the answer giving explicit steps.